# Excel update slicer from VBA function (1004 error)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change a slicer in my excel document with VBA code. So far i've tried just about everything and i always end up with the same error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Here is my current VBA code.

```
Sub SelectSlicerValue(ByVal SlicerName As String, ByVal slicerVal As String, ByVal isSelected As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).SlicerItems(slicerVal).Selected = isSelected
End Sub

'Selects slicer values to display only data for 17-year old male students
Sub SelectMale17Profile()
    SelectSlicerValue "Slicer_Age1", "17", True
End Sub
```

I believe i've read somewhere, that i need to enable the read/write properties of the slicer before I'm able to dynamically change the selected filters. How do i do this?

Comment: It works just fine for me. Also when you are setting one to true, then set rest to false. Also is your Pivot table getting data from an external source?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks for your reply!

Yes, I'm using powerpivot to connect to my sql database. Is this a problem, or is it still possible to change the slicer with VBA?

Comment: @Ralph, thanks for your reply! I downloaded your example and it's working exactly like i want it to, but i can't seem to get it to work on my own project. I'm guessing it's because my pivot table is connected to an external source, since SiddharthRout asked about it in his comment. Can I get the same effect if the pivot table is connected to a SQL server?

Comment: I just did a test run with the above Excel file and connected it to my local MS SQL 2014. It worked flawlessly. So, you're probably facing a problem with the connection / authentication / refresh or something else in that respect.

Comment: Just to be safe: you know that the slicer name (NameOfSlicerAsShownOnSheet) is not the one to be used in VBA but rather `SelectSlicerValue "Slicer_NameOfSlicerAsShownOnSheet", "17", True`. Other than that there is nothing more that I can think of and you'll probably have to look into the Excel / SQL connection which is automatically initiated when you use a slicer (auto-refresh). If nothing else works. You can also copy the SQL data into the Excel file and do the pivoting there (as done in my above example). Then it will work as shown (without SQL connection problems).

Comment: @Ralph. I believe I'm using the correct name. I've tested it with this code:

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_SynshalCVRNummer").Slicers("SynshalCVRNummer").Width = 330

This changes the width of the slicer I want, but this creates and error:

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_SynshalCVRNummer").SlicerItems(slicerVal).Selected = true

Answer (score 1):

> @SiddharthRout - Thanks for your reply! Yes, I'm using powerpivot to connect to my sql database. Is this a problem, or is it still possible to change the slicer with VBA? – TobiasKnudsen 6 hours ago

If your Pivot table is getting data from an external source then use the `SlicerCacheLevels` collection to loop through the items in the slicer and do what you want. For Example

```
'Selects slicer values to display only data for 17-year old male students
Sub SelectMale17Profile()
    SelectSlicerValue "Slicer_Age1", "17", True
End Sub

Sub SelectSlicerValue(ByVal SlicerName As String, ByVal slicerVal As String, ByVal isSelected As Boolean)
    Dim oSitm As SlicerItem
    Dim oSlvl As SlicerCacheLevel

    For Each oSlvl In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).SlicerCacheLevels
        For Each oSitm In oSlvl.SlicerItems
            If oSitm.Value = slicerVal Then oSitm.Selected = isSelected
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

On a different perspective, I think this is what you are trying to do? I removed the `isSelected`.

```
'Selects slicer values to display only data for 17-year old male students
Sub SelectMale17Profile()
    SelectSlicerValue "Slicer_Age1", "17", True
End Sub

Sub SelectSlicerValue(ByVal SlicerName As String, ByVal slicerVal As String)
    Dim oSitm As SlicerItem
    Dim oSlvl As SlicerCacheLevel

    For Each oSlvl In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).SlicerCacheLevels
        For Each oSitm In oSlvl.SlicerItems
            If oSitm.Value = slicerVal Then
                oSitm.Selected = True
            Else
                oSitm.Selected = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I do this exact code but selecting each value of the slicer, and not just one in specific?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question. Can you elaborate a little bit as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to do a for loop through slicer items and do something considering my slicer is connected to an external source (needed to use SlicerCacheLevels in this case just like you did). I alrealdy figured out another way to do it, but it would be nice to see your suggestion. It's different from your answer because I would want all the items and not just the items that were equal to 17.

Comment: A simple loop will solve your problem. simply omit the comparision part?

Answer (score 0):

If your pivot tables use external data source try SlicerCache.VisibleSlicerItems property. It works without any issues.

```
Workbooks("WorkbookName").SlicerCaches("Slicer_Something_Something").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[Table].[Column].&[ItemSelection]")
```

Try recording a macro while you change slicer selection. It should record the above with the exact object names.